# How to print out SQL Statements with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have declared Variables that i got from tkinter Entrys and I work with MySql connector. Now I want to know how to make a SQL Statement and print it out. Thats what I have know:

```
def suche():
    isbn = ISBNE.get()
    vnr = VNRE.get()
    titel = TitelE.get()
    Genre = GenreE.get()
    autorvor = AutorE.get()
    #cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bücher WHERE titel LIKE \""+titel+"\" AND 
    #AutorVorname LIKE \""+autorvor+"\" AND isbn LIKE\""+isbn+"\"")
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bücher WHERE titel LIKE '%s'" % titel)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row!=None:
        print(row)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(isbn)
```

but this doesn't work for me

Comment: How does it ‘not work for you’? Are you getting an error? Also, that code looks like it prints the data returned from the database, not the SQL statement.

Comment: Never of `%` string formatting in SQL strings. This will lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use simple string formatting to construct a SQL query string. Use a parametrized query instead:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bücher WHERE titel LIKE %s" , (titel,))
```

See the dokumentation for it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

The reason behind this is SQL-Injection, a funny explanation can be found here: https://xkcd.com/327/ . Sql injection is dangerous and can lead to damage on your database.

row-based fetching and printing data is described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html):

> ```
> # Using a while loop
> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
> row = cursor.fetchone()
> while row is not None:
>   print(row)
>   row = cursor.fetchone()
> ```

---

Untested pseudo code:

You can extract your isbn, vnr, title, genre out of each `row` and store them elsewise - or copy it into your own data structs:

```
def Book:
    def __init__(self, isbn,name,vnr,genre):
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.name = name
        self.vnr = vnr
        self.genre = genre

def Suche(title):
    books = []
    cursor.execute("SELECT isbn,name,vnr,genre FROM bücher WHERE titel LIKE %s", (titel,))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row is not None:
        isbn,name,vnr,genre = row
        books.append(Book(isbn,name,vnr,genre))
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    print(books)
    return books


# call as:
books = Suche(TitelE.get())
```